# Laravel Eloquent query on first relation of one to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have Two Tables A and B
A can have more than B
the relation between them is that B has A_id
columns in B have A_id and date
I have a filter with status (status alpha = first B of A date is less than 30 days,beta = first B of A date is less than 60)
when trying to get the status I want to query on the first row in B which has A_id

```
public function alpha(){
    return $this->hasOne("App/B")->where('date','<',now()->subMonth(1)->toDateString())->where('date','>',now()->subMonth(2)->toDateString());
}
public function beta(){
    return $this->hasOne("App/B")->where('date','<',now()->subMonth(2)->toDateString());
}
```

This seems to get the job done but failed in specific situation
imagine table B has two rows

1. id = 1 A_id=1 and date is 45 days old
2. id =2 A_id=1 and date is 70 days old

This should be an alpha since I'm only interested in the **First** date
but the query I've written returns on both alpha and beta
how can I fix my query to only check the first occurrence only
mind that I can't loop over A's after getting them since I'm using pagination

Comment: Your conditions are not exclusive to each other, one is `older than 1 month`, and the other is `older than 2 months`, which can both be true at the same time. You will need to add another condition on alpha : `$this->hasOne("App/B")->where('date','>=',now()->subMonth(2)->toDateString())->where('date','<',now()->subMonth(1)->toDateString());`

Comment: Yes That was my mistake I didn't post the whole alpha code I edited it thankyou and no it is still not working even with this as when calling whereHas('beta') it's considering the 2 one as true which is the problem I want it to consider only the first

Comment: You need to consider is how your date is stored, carbon has issues with date matching if its not as timestamp / date / datetime in the database. How is your date being stored?

Comment: There is no problem with the date The problem is I want to check the first relation only (This is the problem beta is retrieving the second row because it is valid I want it to check the first relation only )